# install mongodb on window 8

Tags: mongodb, service

I try to install mongodb on window 8 .

problem is when i want to install mongodb service

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --auth --config C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg --install
```

below error accord

```
 Wed Mar 13 19:13:23 Trying to install Windows service 'MongoDB'
 Wed Mar 13 19:13:23 Error connecting to the Service Control Manager: Access is denied. (5)
```

how Can I Install Mongodb Service?

Comment: Are you sure you have administrator privileges on the system?

Comment: @Sammaye yes i test it on administrator user

Comment: I think this question might be a better fit in [superuser.stackexchange.com](http://superuser.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for answer `Moacy Barros` but problem was not for this because i run all commands in Command Prompt with “Administrative Privileges:”" problem was for `mongod.cfg` if  `mongod.cfg` config by manual in editor this problem solve that we didn't need to do this in window 7 or server 2008

Edit::

in older windows when [installing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-directories-and-files) MongoDB < 2.2 `that i was tested`. in `Configure directories and files` step

```
echo logpath="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\log\mongo.log" > "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod.cfg"
```

it make  `mongod.cfg`  for your mongodb but it wasn't  make  for me in `window 8` for that i make it by manual  like

```
logpath=C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log 
logappend=true
dbpath = E:\data
```

Comment: can you please explain more clearly what the solution was? I don't understand what you mean by "problem was for mongod.cfg if mongod.cfg config by manual in editor this problem solve". Perhaps you could post  your config problem before or after.

Comment: @schmidlop I think he meant that he couldn't create the config file with the `echo` command (probably because of file permissions).

Answer (score 10):

Open Command with **"Run as Administrator"**,that solved my problem

Answer (score 6):

For anyone that happens to try to create a mongodb service on Windows 8 and follows the instructions on MongoDB's website AND still is unable to create the service successfully - I've written this post that explains how I got it to work after experiencing problems trying to set the mongo service on my Windows 8 laptop. Hope it helps!

Here are the steps that you really need to follow to create a Windows service for MongoDB in Windows 8:

**Installing MongoDB on Windows 8**

1. Download and install MongoDB. You can download the 32 or 64-bit version from here.
2. Make sure you install MongoDB in a folder that you can easily remember, for example: c:\mongodb\
3. Add directories c:\mongodb\log and c:\mongodb\data
4. Add log file c:\mongodb\log\mongo.log

**Creating a Windows service for MongoDB**

5. Open your command window and type the following:

   cd c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --install --rest -master -logpath=c:\mongodb\log\mongo.log
6. Open the registry settings, press the Windows key and R at the same time and then type **regedit** in the Run command window.
7. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE >> SYSTEM >> CurrentControlSet >> services
8. Find out MongoDB directory & edit ImagePath key
   Set key value as:

   C:\mongodb\bin\mongod --service  --rest  --master  --logpath=C:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log  --dbpath=C:\mongodb\data
9. Save and exit registry editor.
10. Open Services by pressing the Windows key and R at the same time and then type services.msc in the Run command window and click OK.
11. Find the MongoDB service and right-click on it, select Properties
12. Make sure the service is set to start automatically and start the service as shown below.

[image]

13. Open your browser and go to `http://localhost:28017/` to see if MongoDB is running correctly, you should see a page full of MongoDB details.

Link to this blog post:
http://ricardodsanchez.com/2014/09/03/install-mongodb-service-on-windows-8/

Answer (score 1):

error message suggest you don't have admin privileges.

"Run all of the following commands in Command Prompt with “Administrative Privileges:”"

Ref: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#install-and-run-the-mongodb-service

Regards,
Moacy

Comment: thanks for answer but problem was not for this because i run all commands in Command Prompt with “Administrative Privileges:”"problem was for `mongod.cfg` if  `mongod.cfg` config by manual this problem solve that you didn't need to do this in window 7 or server 2008