# How to install MongoDB as service on Windows 8.1

Tags: mongodb

I am running Windows 8.1 64 bit, MongoDb 2.6.0, I am running as administrator

This is the command I am running:

```
c:\mongo\bin\mongod.exe --logpath "C:\mongo\logs\server.log" --dbpath "C:\mongo\data\db" --install
```

This is the error I receive, note that this error appears in the log file!

```
--install has to be used with --logpath
```

I've read these, and tried the suggestions from these other questions to no avail
[install mongodb on window 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395031/install-mongodb-on-window-8)
[How to set MongoDB as a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876523/how-to-set-mongodb-as-a-windows-service)

Comment: Also note that it works (not as a service) when I remove the --install from the command

Comment: might be better asked on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bug. It has been fixed 2 hours ago but will be part of 2.6.1. See Jira Issue [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13515?jql=text%20~%20%22windows%20service%22%20AND%20updated%20%3E=%20-3d)

As a workaround you can install 2.4.9 as Windows Service and then replace the files with 2.6 with a simple copy & paste

Comment: I know it is agains the site rules, but, THANKS YOU!, after an hour scratching my head I found this solution, this kind of bugs are really outrageous.

Answer (score 2):

Using "sc create" as described Ray's article did the trick for me.

So instead of;

```
"C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg" --install
```

Use this;

```
sc create MongoDB binPath= "C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --config=C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg --service" displayname= "MongoDB 3.0 Standard Server" start= auto
```

Start the service with

```
net start MongoDB
```

I you want to change the startup behaviour later on you can use the GUI.

1. Open a run box; `Win + R`
2. Type services.msc and press return
3. Double click the MongoDB service  to show the properties screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the [Jira issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13515?jql=text%20~%20%22windows%20service%22%20AND%20updated%20%3E%3D%20-3d) has been updated with a proper set of manual service installation instructions. It's not necessary to go through the 2.4.9 installation Kabuki. I had no problem installing a 2.6.0 service on a new Windows 2012 server.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog about it that outlines some key points:

http://www.troubleshootingcenter.com/2014/04/19/installing-mongodb-2-6-and-configuring-it-as-a-windows-service-windows-8-1/

Comment: It's better to leave a brief explanation here, and reference the link for details.