# MongoDB windows service install

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to configure windows 7 (32 bit) service for MongoDB with that cmd command:
    mongod.exe -f mongo.conf --install --serviceName mongoDB --serviceDisplayName "MongoDB windows service" --serviceDescription "MongoDB"

```
-f mongo.conf is a reference to my configuration file located in the same directory with mongod.exe.
this is how my mongo.conf looks like:
dbpath = C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\data
logpath = C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\logs\mongo.log
port = 27017

and yet, when i'm trying to run the command, mongo logs to me:
--install has to be used with --logpath

anyone has an idea what is wrong with that?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install MongoDB as service on Windows 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969325/how-to-install-mongodb-as-service-on-windows-8-1)

Comment: It's likely you're hitting the same bug as in the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path in the `-f` argument:

```
--install -f "C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\mongod.conf"
```

(caveat: I haven't tried this with whitespaces in the folder names)

Services working directory isn't the directory that you install them from or that their exe resides in, but the [%windir%\system32 directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884963/what-directory-does-a-windows-service-run-in).